# Base64 utility in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I run into a specific issue when try to convert an image binary (with a 0xFFD8 jpeg signature) to a base64 string using awk. It looks to me that I am almost there but the base64 string is truncated and not complete. Since the image binary is large, I am not sure if that causes the issue. The command producing this is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk --field-separator '|' '{ "echo "$mybinaryhere" | xxd -r -p | base64" | getline x print x }' myfile.csv
```

The output is:

```
/9j/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMU
```

Expected output should be similar but much longer because it is a binary image. The `$mybinaryhere` is just a column variable which holds the full binary image when `awk` is reading `myfile.csv`

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your code to us which you tried(always do so in your questions), could you please do show sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and do let us know then.

Comment: Where does `mybinaryhere` come from? The `awk` script, as shown, isn't using its input at all.

Comment: That said, `awk` is not designed for binary data. It's going to interpret any 0 bytes as a string terminator, which probably accounts for the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I updated some more info

Comment: @chepner - I updated some more info for the variable

Comment: I'm still very confused about both `mybinaryhere` and the source data. Is `mybinaryhere` a shell variable? Does it contain raw image data, hex image data, or a column number in the file that contains one of those, or something else? Also, this isn't valid `awk` syntax in any variant I'm familiar with.

Comment: If your objective is to encode jpeg file in base64, why don't you just say  `base64 file.jpg` or something similar (without `awk`)?

Comment: gawk (and probably other versions) have a limit in on the length of the string that can be piped into getline. It's 131072 on the one I have here (ie. 128kB)

Comment: @GordonDavisson it is a column number which contains the hex image data (jpeg). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @GordonDavisson I think the OP forgot a semicolon before print

Comment: @tshiono well because the csv file contains the hex image and other data fields. Not only the image file itself

Comment: @jhnc I think you are right on the maximum length of the string that can be piped into awk getline. I would mark this as an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `base64` is wrapped at an appropriate column size (76 columns)
and each line ends with a newline. The `getline` function of `awk` just reads
next single line from the standard input and the remaining lines will be discarded.
Then would you please try:

```
awk --field-separator '|' '{ while ("echo "$mybinaryhere" | xxd -r -p | base64" | getline) print }' myfile.csv
```

Comment: Worked beautifully :) - Thanks a bunch

Comment: Still what's the purpose of Awk here? Doesn't `echo "$mybinaryhere" | xxd -r -p | base64` do what you want?

Comment: @tripleee to read my csv file which hold couple columns and the hex image

Comment: So `while IFS='|' read -r foo binary baz; do echo "$binary" | xxd -r -r | base64; done <myfile.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

gawk (and other versions of awk) have a limit on the length of the command string that can be piped into `getline`.

For example, on an ubuntu box, I get:

```
bash$ for a in gawk 'busybox awk'; do
  for x in 131059 131060; do
      echo "$a :"
      perl -e 'print "." x '$x',"\n"' |\
      $a '{
        y=$1
        print length($1)+length("echo |md5sum")
        "echo "y"|md5sum" | getline z
        print z
      }'
  done
done
gawk :
131071
3ee42da12241d3e96a1513588bf50daf  -
gawk :
131072

busybox awk :
131071
3ee42da12241d3e96a1513588bf50daf  -
busybox awk :
131072

$
```

On FreeBSD, I get:

- awk: 261764
- nawk: 261763